# warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T? (al compilar en Free Pascal)

Tags: freepascal

al parecer tengo un problema con este codigo en free pascal, el cual al compilarlo me salta un cartel que dice "warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?" y para ser sincero no tengo ni la minima idea de que puede ser, estoy aprendiendo a programar asi que podria ser un error algo tonto de resolver.

Espero me ayuden,gracias

```
program ejerciciodeterminante  (input,output);

var determinante, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16 : real;

begin

read(a1, a2, a3, a4);
read(a5, a6, a7, a8);
read(a9, a10, a11, a12);
read(a13, a14, a15, a16);


if ((a3 <= a4) or (a3 >= a4)) then

       determinante :=((a1 * a6 * a11 * a16) + (a3 * a8 * a9 * a14) + (a4 * a10 * a7 * a13) + (a5 * a12 * a2 * a15) - (a2 * a7 * a12 * a13) - (a4 * a10 * a15 * a5) - (a11 * a1 * a8 * a14) - (a3 * a6 * a9 * a16));
       writeln(determinante);
       


if not ((a3 <= a4) or (a3 >= a4)) then
     

       determinante := (a1 * a6 * a11) + (a5 * a10 * a3) + (a9 * a2 * a7) - (a3 * a6 * a9) - (a7 * a10 * a1) - (a11 * a2 * a5);

       writeln(determinante);
       
if not ((a3 <= a2) or (a3 >= a2)) then
         
       determinante :=  (a1 * a6) - (a2 * a5);
     
       writeln(determinante);

if not ((a1 <= a2) or (a1 >= a2)) then

       determinante := a1;
     
       writeln(determinante);
     


     
end.
```

Comment: Creo que se trata de un bug dentro de linux/free pascal, por lo he he leído, la recomendación es actualizar o simplemente ignorar el _warning_.  Más info en las [FAQ de FreePascal](https://www.freepascal.org/faq.var#unix-ld219) (en inglés).